# Trouble using "sed" command?

Tags: linux, sed, terminal

I would like to use `sed` to add a comma (`,`) at the end of each line of my .txt file.  I used this `sed` command:

```
sed 's/$/,/'
```

but instead of giving me this output:

> ```
> 27,
> 2,
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> 30,
> ```

it shows this:

> ```
> 35
> ,
> 1
> ,
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> 15
> ,
> ```

That is, it added each comma on a new line.  How can I fix that?

Also, what command can I use to remove the last character of those lines that contain three-digit numbers or end with non-digits?

And one more question: if I would like to use a `for` loop to run the code on all the text files in a directory then do I have to make a bash script?

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to use `sed` to add a comma (,) at the end of each line of my .txt file.

Your original `sed` command works for me as you seem to want on a text file containing a series of one- and two-digit numbers, one to a line:

> ```
> $ sed 's/$/,/' <<EOF
> 1
> 17
> 99
> 0
> 23
> EOF
> 1,
> 17,
> 99,
> 0,
> 23,
> ```

Possibly your file has non-standard line terminators (e.g. Windows line terminators), but in my environment, with GNU sed v4.2.2, that produced a *different* unwanted behavior than the one you describe.  Still, it couldn't hurt to run `dos2unix` on the input, and / or to verify that it doesn't contain any unexpected non-printing characters.

But if you want

> to remove the last character of those lines that contain three-digit
>   numbers or end with non-digits?

*on the same files* then that's moot, as an altogether different approach is probably warranted, something like this, maybe:

```
sed 's/^\([0-9]\{1,2\}\).*/\1,/'
```

Example:

> ```
> $ sed 's/^\([0-9]\{1,2\}\).*/\1,/' <<EOF
> 1
> 17
> 999
> 22c
> 53
>
> oops
> EOF
> 1,
> 17,
> 99,
> 22,
> 53,
>
> oops
> ```

That captures either one or two decimal digits at the beginning of each line, and on those lines where it successfully does so, replaces the whole line with the captured digits followed by a comma.

Of course, that's not exactly what you asked for.  If you really want to only and exactly modify those lines that contain nothing but an exactly three-digit number or that end with a non-digit, by removing the last character, then you're looking at something more like this:

```
sed '/^\([0-9]\{3\}\|.*[^0-9]\)$/ s/.$//'
```

The first, larger part, `/^\([0-9]\{3\}\|.*[^0-9]\)$/`, is a regular expression matching those lines you want to modify: a line containing nothing but three decimal digits or ending with a non-digit.  The second part is an `s` command that replaces the last character of the line with nothing.

> if I would like to use a `for` loop to run the code on all the text
>   files in a directory then do I have to make a bash script?

No. `sed` accepts multiple filenames on the command line.  It will operate on all files so named.  Or if for some reason you need to feed the files to `sed` on its standard input, then you can `cat` them all together and redirect the result into `sed`.

Or more generally, anything you can write in a bash script, you can also enter directly at the bash prompt, for example

```
$ for f in *.txt; do sed 's/$/,/' $f; done
```

I sometimes do that sort of thing, but it's easier to edit a script than to retype a command line or recall and edit a previous command, and putting it in a script preserves it for the next time you want to do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks man!! It worked and u were right because that txt file was made in Windows. The "dos2unix" worked fine.  Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Use sed Command

```
sed 's/$/,/g' filename
```

input

```
A
B
C
```

Output

```
A,
B,
C,
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure I get what you wanted, but taking a guess at a possible solution -

```
$: cat x
1
23
456
a
7b
89d
000x

$: sed -E 's/^([0-9]{0,2}).*/\1,/' x
1,
23,
45,
,
7,
89,
00,
```

Is that the behavior you were hoping for?

Comment: Yep, but actually when i run the code i only get "," intead of my number. It substituted all the characthers in lines for ","

Comment: Huh. Any possibility of a leading space or something before the first digit?

Answer (score 0):

It may be a formatting problem with your original file.  Try this:

```
dos2unix file

sed 's/$/,/' file
```